# How to use react ref to get value from html select element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a form in which I am using html `select` element.

```
  <select className="form-control" id="ntype" required >
      <option value = "">None</option>
      <option value = "1">1</option>
      <option value = "2">2</option>
      <option value = "3">3</option>
  </select>
```

I know with html `input` type element we can attach `ref` like below code

```
ref = {(input) => { this.nHeading = input; }}
```

and

```
<input
    type        = "text"
    className   = "form-control"
    id          = "tInput"
    placeholder = "Sample input"
    ref         = {(input) => { this.sInput = input; }}
    required
/>
```

How can I attach ref to `<Select>` element and get selected `option value` from the attached `ref` when form is submitted?

Do I need to attach `ref` to each options or `select` element itself?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to do this with refs, rather than have the `<select>` model some other piece of state and use that instead?

Comment: did you try adding it to the select itself and then just using regular javascript on the element? i would also second @rossipedia though if you don't have a good reason for doing it this way

Comment: @rossipedia I don't want to use controlled element via states, I want to use refs instead.

Comment: @aw04 I just don't want  to store state with form elements, because Component already has other important states. It may not be good reason but still I want to do it in ref way :)

Comment: sure, i think the bottom part of the answer by @Shubham Khatri is the literal answer to your question then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the value in a state on change and later use that i.e make it a controlled component

```js
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();
    this.state = {selectValue: ''}
    }
    callThis = (e) => {
        this.setState({selectValue: e.target.value}, ()=> {console.log(this.state.selectValue)});
        
    }
    render() {
    
      return (
          <select onChange={this.callThis}className="form-control" id="ntype" required >
              <option value = "">None</option>
              <option value = "1">1</option>
              <option value = "2">2</option>
              <option value = "3">3</option>
          </select>
         
      )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Or you can use `refs` to get the value like this

```js
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();
    this.state = {selectValue: ''}
    }
    callThis = (e) => {
        console.log(this.selectVal.value)
        
    }
    render() {
    
      return (
          <div><select ref={(input) => this.selectVal = input} className="form-control" id="ntype" required >
              <option value = "">None</option>
              <option value = "1">1</option>
              <option value = "2">2</option>
              <option value = "3">3</option>
          </select>
          <input type="button" value="click" onClick={this.callThis}/></div>
      )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Second example is what I need. I never thought It could be that much easy. Do you still need to store `selectValue` in state?

Comment: No you dont in the second example

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React functional components, you can do the following.

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';

...

  const selectRef = useRef(null)
  <select className="form-control" id="ntype" required ref={selectRef}>
      <option value = "">None</option>
      <option value = "1">1</option>
      <option value = "2">2</option>
      <option value = "3">3</option>
  </select>
```

then you can access the value in your submit logic by,

`selectRef.current.value`

Answer (score 0):

I would give each element a value and onChange handler for the select element like this

```
<select className="form-control"onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}>
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

And define an onChange handler that sets the state of the selection

```
onChange(e){
    this.setState({value: e.target.value}, function(){

    // do other stuff

});
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can just use an onChange function to set the value of the Ref. E.g.:

```
<select className="form-control" id="ntype" required onChange={e => {yourRef.current = e.target.value}} >
      <option value = "">None</option>
      <option value = "1">1</option>
      <option value = "2">2</option>
      <option value = "3">3</option>
  </select>
```